# Can PatternRank extract the keyphrases with infix '-'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I tried to use PatternRank to extract keyphrases from text document with part-of-speech tags. However, some keywords with infix '-', '/', etc. can not be recognized which might be the target, While '_' can be recognized by PatternRank.

Example:

```
import spacy 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keybert import KeyBERT
from keyphrase_vectorizers import KeyphraseCountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

text = ['''BERT is a pre-trained model for NLP.''']
kw_model1.extract_keywords(docs=text, vectorizer=KeyphraseCountVectorizer(spacy_pipeline=nlp, lowercase=False, pos_pattern='<N.*>*<V.*>*<P.*>*<J.*>*<N.*>*', stop_words='english'), use_mmr=True)

>> output: [('BERT is', 0.6578), ('NLP', 0.5684)]
```

But if I replace '-' with '_':

```
import spacy 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keybert import KeyBERT
from keyphrase_vectorizers import KeyphraseCountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

text = ['''BERT is a pre_trained model for NLP.''']
kw_model1.extract_keywords(docs=text, vectorizer=KeyphraseCountVectorizer(spacy_pipeline=nlp, lowercase=False, pos_pattern='<N.*>*<V.*>*<P.*>*<J.*>*<N.*>*', stop_words='english'), use_mmr=True)

>> output: [('BERT is', 0.6579), ('NLP', 0.5666), ('pre_trained model', 0.5215)]
```

I have modify the tokenizer infix patterns with spaCy as below to remain the infix like '-', '/', etc. But it still doesn't work.

```
import re
from spacy.lang.char_classes import ALPHA, ALPHA_LOWER, ALPHA_UPPER
from spacy.lang.char_classes import CONCAT_QUOTES, LIST_ELLIPSES, LIST_ICONS, LIST_PUNCT, LIST_QUOTES, CURRENCY, UNITS, PUNCT, LIST_CURRENCY
from spacy.util import compile_infix_regex, compile_prefix_regex, compile_suffix_regex
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
# Modify tokenizer infix patterns
# Don't want the tokenizer to split on hyphens between letters
infixes = (
    LIST_ELLIPSES
    + LIST_ICONS
    + [
        r"(?<=[0-9])[+\\-\\*^](?=[0-9-])",
        r"(?<=[{al}{q}])\\.(?=[{au}{q}])".format(
            al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER, q=CONCAT_QUOTES
        ),
        r"(?<=[{a}]),(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
        # Commented out regex that splits on hyphens between letters:
        # r"(?<=[{a}])(?:{h})(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, h=HYPHENS),
        r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=/](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
    ]
)

suffixes = (
    LIST_PUNCT
    + LIST_ELLIPSES
    + LIST_QUOTES
    + LIST_ICONS
    + ["'s", "'S", "’s", "’S", "—", "–"]
    + [
        r"(?<=[0-9])\+",
        r"(?<=°[FfCcKk])\.",
        r"(?<=[0-9])(?:{c})".format(c=CURRENCY),
        r"(?<=[0-9])(?:{u})".format(u=UNITS),
        r"(?<=[0-9{al}{e}{p}(?:{q})])\.".format(
            al=ALPHA_LOWER, e=r"%²\-\+", q=CONCAT_QUOTES, p=PUNCT
        ),
        r"(?<=[{au}][{au}])\.".format(au=ALPHA_UPPER),
    ]
)

prefixes = (
    ["§", "%", "=", "—", "–", r"\+(?![0-9])"]
    + LIST_PUNCT
    + LIST_ELLIPSES
    + LIST_QUOTES
    + LIST_CURRENCY
    + LIST_ICONS
)
```